# How to differentiate something with u and x?

Tags: calculus

How can I differentiate this:

$y=u^2+3u$ and $u=1+\sqrt{x}$.

It says answer must be in terms of 
$x$ only not $u$ and $x$.

How is that possible if the first problem does not even have an $x$? Is this a trick question?

Comment: Does that mean 2u+3 = 1 + $\sqrt{x}$?

Comment: OP you should clarify what you mean by differentiate. You could differentiate $y$ with respect to $x$ or you could differentiate $y$ with respect to $u$ or differentiate $u$ with respect to $x$ (or any other combination you want to think about). Please be specific with what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

The problem only makes sense if both $u$ and $y$ are secretly functions of $x$, so the information you're given is actually
$$ \begin{align} y(x) &= u(x)^2+3u(x)\quad  \bigl[ = f(u(x)) \text{ where } f(t) = t^2+3t \bigr]\\
u(x) &= 1+\sqrt x \end{align}$$

Then computing $y'(x)$ is just a matter of applying the chain rule.

---

In *applications* of calculus, it can be quite convenient to write, say, just $u$ instead of $u(x)$ while you're constructing some functions to model whichever real-world problem you're trying to solve. This saves space in the equations, and anything that saves space is a good thing, to an extent, because it makes the equations easier to understand in a glance.

Unfortunately this also requires students to be proficient in keeping track of what is secretly a function of what, and it is common for neither textbooks nor teachers to really explain how these conventions work. With enough practice it can become second nature to figure out what make sense, but until such practice is gained, a major source of trouble for beginning calculus students is not the *calculus* itself, but merely understanding the conventions of writing down the functions that are being worked on.

Answer (score 1):

Hint : $$\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}=\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm du}\frac{\mathrm du}{\mathrm dx}.$$

Comment: How do three fractions relate to the problem in the OP? I have dyscalculia and cannot understand math concepts like that. Do you mean that I should rewrite the stuff in the OP to fit into the fractions setup?

Comment: @user6050977: What is being suggested is the *chain rule* of calculus, though indeed it is possible you do not recognize it as such.  Your terse statement of the problem gives little hint of where you might have been having difficulty with solving it, and sometimes a cogent hint like this (a reminder of the principle an exercise is meant to illustrate) is appropriate).  Hopefully you already found one of the other Answers useful, but in any case keep in mind the need for context in future Question.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you are maybe not acquainted with the chain rule suggested in Tom-Tom's and Henning's answers (though you probably should be if this kind of exercises is posed to you right now). So here's an alternate way to handle it: Just substitute every $u$ in the $y=\ldots$ equation according to the value given to $u$ by the $u=\ldots$ equation. You will end up with "$y$ equals some expression in $x$", and maybe you can handle differentiating that that more easily ...

Answer (score 1):

(1) You can substitute and then differentiate:

$$u=1+\sqrt x\implies y=u^2+3u=\overbrace{x+1+2\sqrt x}^{=u^2}+\overbrace{3+3\sqrt x}^{=3u}=x+5\sqrt x+4\implies$$

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=1+\frac5{2\sqrt x}$$

(2) You can apply the chain rule to $\;y(u(x))\;$:

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{du}\frac{du}{dx}=(2u+3)\cdot\frac1{2\sqrt x}=\frac u{\sqrt x}+\frac32\frac1{\sqrt x}=\frac{1+\sqrt x}{\sqrt x}+\frac3{2\sqrt x}=1+\frac5{2\sqrt x}$$